# Firestore transaction - Type error

Tags: angular, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm following along with the documentation (first example [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions)) but I'm getting an error for some reason. It's expecting an argument of type `DocumentReference` but the variable I'm passing in is of type `AngularFirestoreDocument<{}>`. I can't seem to cast it. Here's the code:

```
      //Get Pins counter
      let pathRef = 'PlaceOne/'+this.Place2;
      var pinDocRef = this.afs.doc(pathRef);

      //Run Transaction
      return this.afs.firestore.runTransaction(function(transaction){
        return transaction.get(pinDocRef).then(function(pinDoc){
          if(!pinDoc.exists){
            throw "Document does not exist!"
          }

          var newPinScore = pinDoc.data().pins + 1;
          transaction.update(pinDocRef, { pins: newPinScore });
        });
      })
```

**Gives me this error:**

[image: Transaction error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve it without `angularfire` using firebase native method.

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Then inside your function

```
let pinDocRef = firebase.firestore().collection('PlaceOne').doc(this.Place2);

  return firebase.firestore().runTransaction(function(transaction) {
    // This code may get re-run multiple times if there are conflicts.
    return transaction.get(pinDocRef).then(function(pinDoc) {
        if(!pinDoc.exists){
            throw "Document does not exist!"
        }

        let newPinScore = pinDoc.data().pins + 1;
        transaction.update(pinDocRef, { pins: newPinScore });
    });
  }).then(function() {
      console.log("Transaction successfully committed!");
  }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log("Transaction failed: ", err);
  });
```

If you want to use `Angularfire` way try

```
var pinDocRef = this.afs.doc(pathRef).ref;
```

i am not sure about the second way.

Comment: That fixed the issue, thanks man. Not sure why the documentation didn't need the `.ref` at the end.